# C++ Pass Mutex By Reference for Different Instances

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I want to share a mutex between different instances of a class, whose functions are running as threads. Is the way I have written it okay? (I don't think I need to be using a shared_mutex, although that might be better practice. Would I pass that in the same way?)

```
class A
{
 public:

     // Execute some work that locks some piece of data by acquiring the mutex.
     void execute(std::mutex & myMutex);
}

class B
{

 public:
     void execute(std::shared_ptr<A> a)
     {

        //   Create the Threads for execution.
        //   Changed to correct syntax.
        std::thread t1(&B::runThread, this, a);
        std::thread t2(&B::runThread, this, a);

        t1.join();            
        t2.join();
     };

     void runThread(std::shared_ptr<A> a)
     {
         a->execute(std::ref(theMutex));
     }



 private:

 //   The Mutex to share with the threads.
 std::mutex theMutex;

}
```

Comment: Why not making the thread (function) a member of the class instead?

Comment: I've edited to make the use case clearer, but essentially I want to derive from the class A and pass that in later. Then the derived class of A can use the mutex as it sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the code as posted won't compile: `B::runThread()` is a non-`static` member and, thus, takes an implicit object as argument. You'll need to create the thread using using something like this:

```
std::thread t(&B::runThread, this, a);
```

Assuming `B::theMutex` does appropriately protect the resource shared between multiple threads when using `A::execute()` the approach to share a mutex between different threads is what mutexes are for. Since the question is devoid of any detail it can't be answered whether a mutex is the appropriate synchronization primitive: depending on the actual use in `A::execute()` other approaches may be more appropriate to avoid serialization, dead-locks, etc.

The use of a `std::shared_mutex` is in essentially all cases the wrong approach and is certainly **not** "better practice". The situations where a `std::shared_mutex` actually does result in a better approach are extremely rare. In practice I have never seen a case where using something like a `std::shared_mutex` resulted in improved performance (I haven't see `std::shared_mutex` in the wild but the POSIX counter parts or wrapper thereof I have encountered surprisingly often). Instead, it always resulted in worse performance than using normal `std::mutex`es and it had extremely bad worst-case behavior: when there were lots of changes (i.e. exclusive locks) it frequently resulted in dramatic stalls of the entire system.

Comment: Okay. I just want to make sure. Assume `B::theMutex` does protect the shared resource when only one thread acquires it. So, even though each thread gets a reference to the mutex, when one thread attempts to lock it, only that thread will acquire the mutex, right?